# AS3 fl.controls.TextInput and mobile platforms

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, textinput

I intent to use fl.controls.TextInput in a pure-ActionScript Flex project. The fl.controls.TextInput will be transported to Flex by extracting a SWC from Flash Pro CS5.5.

The question is this : if I create an iOS or Android app through Flex, will the TextInput work on the mobile platforms? When the user touches it, will the soft-keyboard appear on screen for the user to enter his input?

Answer (score 1):

The Mobile ActionScript virtual machine ***should*** respect your controls. However, you are taking Flash Player 10.0 tech and running it in a Flex Mobile App (which these days likely means Flex 4.0 / Player 11.0 +). Do you have a compelling reason for not using the Spark Components, or a Flex MXML Layout for forms, etc. Its relatively easy to integrate with ActionScript Projects (which can be loaded into a SpriteVisualElement) and Flex Layout.

I haven't tested the fl.controls.TextInput, but if you take Flash CS 5.5 / CS 6 and attempt to import fl.controls.TextInput, it is a compile time error, since the TextInput is not available past Flash Player version 10.2 +.